# Sum of how many numbers should N be partitioned

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, number-theory

Partition of integer:

```
4 = 4                 p(4,1) = 1
  = 1+3, 2+2          p(4,2) = 2
  = 1+1+2             p(4,3) = 1
  = 1+1+1+1           p(4,4) = 1
```

/max(p(4, k)) = 2, at k = 2

```
5 = 5                 p(5,1) = 1
  = 1+4, 2+3          p(5,2) = 2
  = 1+1+3, 1+2+2      p(5,3) = 2
  = 1+1+1+2           p(5,4) = 1
  = 1+1+1+1+1         p(5,5) = 1
```

/max(p(5, k)) = 2, at k  = 2 and 3

and `p(n) = Σp(n, k) for ∀k: 0<k<=n`

p(4) = p(4, 1) + p(4, 2) + p(4, 3) + p(4, 4) = 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 5

p(5) = p(5, 1) + p(5, 2) + p(5, 3) + p(5, 4) + p(5, 5) = 1 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7

for this I used Euler's Identity `p(n, k) = p(n-1, k-1) + p(n-k, k)`

```
#p(n, k) = p(n-1, k-1) + p(n-k, k)
N = int(input())
p = [[0]*(N+1) for i in range(N+1)]
for i in range(N+1):
    p[i][1] = 1
    p[i][i] = 1
for n in range(2, N+1):
    for k in range(2, n+1):
        p[n][k] = p[n-1][k-1] + p[n-k][k]
print(sum(p[-1])) 
for x in p:
    print(x[1:])
    print(sum(x))
```

Using above code I could have been able to find partition of Integer: `p(N)` i.e The total number of ways in which a given number `n` can be expressed as sum of all positive integers.

But, Now I want to find the value of `k` for which `p(n, k)` is maximum.

But **without using Euler's Identity** in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rather small `n` values you can implicitly generate all partitions, count number of parts in every partition.

```
n = 7
kcounts = [0]*n

def parts(sum, last = 1, k=0):
    if sum == 0:
        global kcounts
        kcounts[k-1] += 1
        return

    for i in range(last, sum + 1):
        parts(sum - i, i, k + 1)

parts(n)
print(kcounts)

>>[1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

So k=3 gives maximum partitions

Comment: Woww! ingenious! such a clever solution + so simple!
You could have explain your code.

Comment: Note it is not suitable for large `n` because number of partition grows exponentialy. For optimization one might apply some kind of tables, dynamic programming, and perhaps the best is Euler's identity ;)

Comment: P.S. I noticed that you have never marked answers to your questions as solutions. Are you aware about such possibility?

Comment: Yes Euler's identity is working for n<2000 and p(2000) is too big to digest!

Comment: No I don't know how to mark as answer i'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: [To accept - gray V mark at the left](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following :

```
N = int(input())
p = [[0]*(N+1) for i in range(N+1)]

maximum = 0
k_number = 0
ans = []
for i in range(N+1):
    p[i][1] = 1
    p[i][i] = 1
for n in range(2, N+1):
    k_number, maximum = 0, 0
    for k in range(2, n+1):
        p[n][k] = p[n-1][k-1] + p[n-k][k]
        if p[n][k] > maximum :
              maximum = p[n][k] 
              k_number = k
              n_for_max = n
    ans.append([n, k_number, maximum])
print(sum(p[-1])) 
for x in p:
    print(sum(x))
for x in ans:
    print(x)
#print('k_number: ',k_number)
```

Comment: Thanks! But, I wanted without using Euler's Identity. (Dynamic)
& Edited Your Code to keep track of all `k`s ∀n can `print(ans[-1])` . Also there could be two values of `k` with `max(p(n, k))` when both equal and maximum at the same ex.`p(8,3)=p(8,4) and also max for n = 8` you can change condition.